# Static files are not loading in Django project in replit

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, replit

I am working on a project using Python-Django in repl.it. When I set DEBUG=True in settings.py, the static files are loading fine but when DEBUG is set to False (DEBUG=False), the static files are not loading and getting 404 error on the console. Please help me in fixing it. I am assuming there should be a place where we need to define static location like we do in nginx config file as follows

```
  location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/example.com/current/static/;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```

Here is my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

if SECRET_KEY is None:
    print(
        "Please setup a SECRET_KEY in the Secrets (Environment variables) tab. See README.md for more."
    )
    exit(1)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
#Change this to "True" to show debug info!
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = '*'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'authenticator',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_root")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

and the below is my folder structure

```
|--authenticator
|  |--migrations
|  |--static
|  |--templates
|  |--views.py,urls.py, etc
|--django_project
|  |--urls.py,settings.py, etc
|--static_root
|--db.sqlite3
|--manage.py
|--README.md
|Packeger files (replit specific)
|--poetry.lock
|--pypproject.toml
```

I tried adding adding the following in the pyproject.toml file

```
[static]
location = "/static_root"
```

but did not work.